# Does ExecuteScalar() have any advantages over ExecuteReader()?

Tags: c#

Does `ExecuteScalar()` have any advantages over `ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: Scaler for retrieving single values, Reader for multiple values.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` only returns the first value from the first row of the dataset. Internal it is treated just like `ExecuteReader()`, a `DataReader` is opened, the value is picked and the `DataReader` gets destroyed afterwards. I also always wondered about that behavior, but it has one advantage: It takes place within the Framework...and you can't compete with the Framework in manners of speed.

**Edit By rwwilden:**
Taking a look with Reflector inside `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` you can see these lines:

```
SqlDataReader ds = this.RunExecuteReader(
    CommandBehavior.Default, RunBehavior.ReturnImmediately, true, "ExecuteScalar");
obj2 = this.CompleteExecuteScalar(ds, false);
```

Exactly what happens inside `ExecuteReader`. Another advantage is that `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` when no data is read. If you use `ExecuteReader`, you'd have to check this yourself.

Answer (score 15):

From [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to
>   retrieve a single value (for example,
>   an aggregate value) from a database.
>   **This requires less code than using the ExecuteReader method, and then
>   performing the operations that you
>   need to generate the single value
>   using the data returned by a
>   SqlDataReader.**

Also from [What is the difference between ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteScalar](http://dng-ado.blogspot.com/2007/05/what-is-difference-between.html)

- **ExecuteReader** :Use for accessing
  data. It provides a forward-only,
  read-only, connected recordset.
- **ExecuteNonQuery** :Use for data
  manipulation, such as Insert, Update,
  Delete.
- **ExecuteScalar** :Use for retriving 1
  row 1 col. value., i.e. Single value.
  eg: for retriving aggregate function.
  It is faster than other ways of
  retriving a single value from DB.

Answer (score 4):

From [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) page on MSDN:

`Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database. This requires less code than using the ExecuteReader  method, and then performing the operations that you need to generate the single value using the data returned by a SqlDataReader`

So, it's not faster or better, but is used to reduce the amount of code written when only one value is needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a single value returned from your Query or SP it's always better to use ExecuteScalar() as it retrieves the first value of the result. Hence, this is faster in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Execute Scalar intended to get single value from the database while Execute Reader to get multiple records into DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar() will take less resources compared to the ExecuteReader() as later will return the multiple column data from the database.

ExecuteReader() will be instantiating the SqlDataReader which is stream based and query the results from the data source