# Using ExecuteScalar() results in a call to ExecuteReader() with a "default" CommandBehaviour?

Tags: executescalar, executereader

Stack trace shows that ExecuteReader is the underlying method for ExecuteScalar.While digging for associated commandbehaviour, i found the post below - stating that the  commandbehaviour.default is used by the reader.

[Does ExecuteScalar() have any advantages over ExecuteReader()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400005/does-executescalar-have-any-advantages-over-executereader)

I'm aware that a connection always can be closed and disposed explicitly using datareader.close(), datareader.dispose() -- provided, ExecuteReader(commandbehaviour.Closeconnection) is used. ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour.Default) on the other hand keeps the underlying connection open even when the datareader object is closed and/or disposed. So my question is, if executescalar uses Default behaviour, how do i ensure that the underlying connection is closed once the scalar value is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# using statement is one of the best things included in the language. It doesn't directly solve your problem, but if you make a standard habit of using it to wrap SQLConnections (and any other type that implements IDisposable) you won't have to worry about a lot of this sort of thing...

```
using(SQLConnection connection = new SQLConnection(...))
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you Loren! Using statement maybe the fastest and easiest way to do it.

Comment: Glad you like it, the using statement is an absolute gem in C#, and should be used way more often than it is