# sql commnad not working for a select statement in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sqlcommand

I'm trying to execute the below code using sql command to get the output and store it in a integer varaible. The code is returning -1 for null values insertion which is fine.

But when there are values in the database table and when proper inputs are given the code is again returning the same -1 value.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

```
try {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"(Select ERSConversionFactorID FROM " + schemaName + "[ERSConversionFactors] WHERE [ERSConversionFactor_CF] = @conversionvalue AND [ERSConversionFactor_Desc] = @convDescription)", con);

    if (comboBox_ConfacValue.Text == "")
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@conversionvalue", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@conversionvalue", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = comboBox_ConfacValue.Text;
    }

    if (combobox_conversionDescription.Text == "")
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@convDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@convDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = combobox_conversionDescription.Text;
    }

    string sql = "Select ERSConversionFactorID FROM " + schemaName + "[ERSConversionFactors] WHERE [ERSConversionFactor_CF] = @conversionvalue AND      [ERSConversionFactor_Desc] = @convDescription)";

    int conversionvalue = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to study this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is not intended to be used to return values from your query. It executes the query but it returns only the number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

If you look at the REMARKS section on [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN you will find the reason of the return value of -1.

With a SELECT command you could use ExecuteReader or better ExecuteScalar if you just want the first column of the first row retrieved by the SELECT statement.
However, because your query has a WHERE statement that could result in no rows retrieved, you should add a check for null on the return value of [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
object result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
     int conversionvalue = Convert.ToInt32(result);
     .....

}
```

Comment: awesome thanks for the information it worked... i will mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try ExecuteScalar

```
int conversionvalue = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar for single values. In this case I would use an ExecuteReader as it seems there is no gaurentee that a single row will always be returned.

```
int? conversionvalue = null; // this will stay null if there is nothing read back
using(var reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()) { // place the use of the reader in a using block to ensure it is cleaned up
    if(reader.Read()) // reader will return true if a record can be read. if you have multiple records you can turn the if into an while loop
        conversionvalue = reader.GetInt32(0); // read the value at ordinal position 0 as an int32
}
```

Comment: It is true that internally ExecuteScalar uses ExecuteReader but take a look at the Remarks section on [ExecuteScalar page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or even [here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400005/does-executescalar-have-any-advantages-over-exec)

Comment: @Steve - thanks, I am aware. I did mention ExecuteScalar was ok for single values but my example included ExecuteReader because of the syntax in the select. If it was `SELECT TOP 1 ...` or `SELECT COUNT()` or something else that indicated that exactly 1 value (or null) would always be returned I would have also have answered with an example of `ExecuteScalar` as well (or not answered at all considering there were 2 fine answers (yours and techspider) with ExecuteScalar already).